# How to pass variables from one page to another in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, variables

I have a login page that when logged in, returns a welcome page with the name of the user on it.
I use this code to pass the variable $user to the welcome page:

```
return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:welcome.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
```

Now on the welcome page I have a nav, with the link to manager.html.twig on it.

This is the code of the link on the welcome page:

```
<li><a href="{{path('login_login_managerPage')}}">Manager</a></li>
```

The link goes to this route:

```
login_login_managerPage:
path:   /managerPage
defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:manager }
```

which points to the managerAction:

```
public function managerAction(Request $request) {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:User');
    if ($session->has('login')) {
        $login = $session->get('login');
        $username = $login->getUsername();
        $password = $login->getPassword();
        $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
        if ($user) {
            return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:manager.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:login.html.twig');
}
```

Now I can't get $user to the managerpage. How can I pass it properly between pages?

EDIT:
I editedy code but now I get this error:

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a NULL variable ("") in LoginLoginBundle:Default:welcome.html.twig at line 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing your own security system, I would recommend you to use Symfony's own security component which has all the important things already done. Please read carefully this link : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Starting from here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form it shows how to get the user from a database.
If you use symfony's security component then you will be able to get current logged in user as follows:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
}
```

In a controller this can be shortcut to:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
}
```

And last in template if you are using twig:

```
<p>Username: {{ app.user.username }}</p>
```

Comment: I get this error when I try your answer:
Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a NULL variable ("") in LoginLoginBundle:Default:welcome.html.twig at line 10